# Compare vector iterator with integer

Tags: c++, vector

```
string str = cpy[i].second;
itr = find(v.begin(), v.end(), str);
auto pos = distance(v.begin(), itr);
//auto pos = itr - v.begin();
if(pos >= v.size() / 2)
    cout << str << " ";
else
    cout << "-" << " ";
```

Here `cpy` is a `vector` of `int` and `string` pair, i.e, `vector<pair<int,string>>cpy`.
The above part gives an error that "**pos does not name a type.**".
How to resolve it?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sounds like you are compiling in C++03 mode, with the compiler thinking that `auto` is a storage class specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change type of pos to int. I think that your compiler doesn't fully support auto.

Comment: I am getting the same problem in multiple compilers.